# PyQt check if value of qlabel changed

Tags: pyqt, label, pyqt4

I Need to check if the value (str) of a qlabel changed.
I think about using the following code (nearly the same as used by a spinbox widget in PyQt):

```
self.connect(self.ui.labelEntry, QtCore.SIGNAL("valueChanged(str)"), self.autovalidate)
```

What's the correct Methode to check if value changed?

All the best;

Answer (score 5):

`QLabels` don't have a valueChanged/textChanged signal. You either have to use another widget type (a QLineEdit for instance) or to subclass QLabel and create your own change-aware class with a `textChanged` signal.

If you use QtDesigner, it might be simpler to go with the first solution and customize your QLineEdit from the Designer. In the property editor, unckeck `frame`, check `readOnly`, and write `background-color:"transparent"` in `styleSheet` and you've got a QLabel looking QLineEdit.

You also should use the [new-style syntax](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html), it's far more elegant.

```
self.ui.labelEntry.textChanged.connect(self.autovalidate)
```